# uncaught exception : -[WebDataSource onGeomagneticModel:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, gyroscope

I am getting an error when my application becomes active again. it returns from background.

I am guessing its my gyro but haven't found a solution.

My error:

```
-[WebDataSource onGeomagneticModel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x37c430
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WebDataSource onGeomagneticModel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x37c430'
```

my applicationDidEnterBackground:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
    NSLog(@"Application moving to background");
    LocationManagerDelegate *locationController = [[LocationManagerDelegate alloc] init];
    [locationController.locationManager stopUpdatingHeading];
    [locationController stopDeviceMotion];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you create another LocationManagerDelegate instance.
So.. the "old" instance you did NOT turn of.

You should add in you .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) LocationManagerDelegate *locationController;
```

Then add above the @implementaion in the .m file

```
@synthesize locationController=locationController_;
```

There where you crate your LocationManagerDelegate you need to change it somehow to (you did not post that part of code):

```
self.locationController = [[[LocationManagerDelegate alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Then change your code to:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
    NSLog(@"Application moving to background");
    [self.locationController.locationManager stopUpdatingHeading];
    [self.locationController stopDeviceMotion];
}
```

Comment: Doh, i my hurry to fix something else i didn't see that...thanks